# How to sort search results on stackoverflow.com by votes?

Tags: feature-request, search

Is there any sort switcher of results on stackoverflow.com?

Or any trick?

I mean specifically the sorting results in such a situation, as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See the tab, to the right of "relevance", that says "votes"? See what happens when you click it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]